# Stop Recursion Once Condition Satisfied

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I am using a CTE to explode out a Bill of Materials and need to locate all those materials that have recursive components.

What I was attempting, was to limit the number of cycles (levels) deep, by setting BOM_Level in the child node to a maximum bound:

```
exec        pr_sys_drop_object '#BOMExploded'
;with BOM
as
(
    select 
        Prod_Plant_CD
    ,   Demand_Plant_CD
    ,   material_cd
    ,   component_cd
    ,   component_quantity
    ,   component_quantity   AS Calculated_Component_Quantity
    ,   BOM_Level
    ,   Demand_Quantity
    ,   CONVERT(float,1)     AS Produced_Ratio
    ,   Material_CD          AS Demand_Material_CD
    from #firstLevel a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        b.Plant_CD as 'Prod_Plant_CD' 
    ,   a.Demand_Plant_CD
    ,   b.Material_CD
    ,   b.Component_CD
    ,   b.component_quantity
    ,   b.component_quantity
    ,   a.BOM_Level + 1
    ,   a.Demand_Quantity
    ,   a.Produced_Ratio * a.Component_Quantity      -- Produced Quantity for the current level = Produced Quantity (level -1) * Component_Quantity (level -1)
    ,   a.Demand_Material_CD
    FROM BOM a 
    inner join #BOM_ProdVersion_Priority b  
        on a.component_cd = b.material_cd
    inner join #base_routes c
        on a.Demand_Plant_CD = c.Recipient_Plant_CD 
       and b.Plant_CD        = c.Source_Plant_CD
       and c.Material_CD     = b.Material_CD   -- Need to have material_cd to link
    where b.Material_CD != b.Component_CD
    and   b.Component_Quantity > 0
    and   BOM_Level < 5 -- Give the max number of levels deep we are allowed to cyncle to
)

select *
into #BOMExploded
from BOM
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 20)
```

Using this method however, would require a post-process to locate when the cycling on the recursive component level started, then back trace.

How can a CTE recursive query be stopped given a certain condition?

`ie. when top-level material_cd = component_cd for a deeper BOM_Level`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you don't need to stop at a certain depth/level, or rather you want to stop at a certain level, but you also need to stop in case you start cycling through materials repeatedly.

In the case of the following recursive path: `mat_1`->`mat_2`->`mat_3`->`mat_1`, you would want to stop before that last `mat_1` starts cycling again to `mat_2` and so on.

If that's correct, then your best bet is to add a `Path` field to your recursive query that tracks each term that it finds as it moves down the recursive path:

```
exec        pr_sys_drop_object '#BOMExploded'
;with BOM
as
(
    select 
        Prod_Plant_CD
    ,   Demand_Plant_CD
    ,   material_cd
    ,   component_cd
    ,   component_quantity
    ,   component_quantity   AS Calculated_Component_Quantity
    ,   BOM_Level
    ,   Demand_Quantity
    ,   CONVERT(float,1)     AS Produced_Ratio
    ,   Material_CD          AS Demand_Material_CD
    ,   CAST(material_cd AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Path
    from #firstLevel a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        b.Plant_CD as 'Prod_Plant_CD' 
    ,   a.Demand_Plant_CD
    ,   b.Material_CD
    ,   b.Component_CD
    ,   b.component_quantity
    ,   b.component_quantity
    ,   a.BOM_Level + 1
    ,   a.Demand_Quantity
    ,   a.Produced_Ratio * a.Component_Quantity      -- Produced Quantity for the current level = Produced Quantity (level -1) * Component_Quantity (level -1)
    ,   a.Demand_Material_CD
    ,   a.Path + '|' + b.material_cd
    FROM BOM a 
    inner join #BOM_ProdVersion_Priority b  
        on a.component_cd = b.material_cd
    inner join #base_routes c
        on a.Demand_Plant_CD = c.Recipient_Plant_CD 
       and b.Plant_CD        = c.Source_Plant_CD
       and c.Material_CD     = b.Material_CD   -- Need to have material_cd to link
    where b.Material_CD != b.Component_CD
    and   b.Component_Quantity > 0
    and   BOM_Level < 5 -- Give the max number of levels deep we are allowed to cyncle to
    and   a.path NOT LIKE '%' + b.material_cd  + '%'
)

select *
into #BOMExploded
from BOM
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 20)
```

Now you have a `path` that is pipe delimited and you can test your current `material_cd` to see if it's already in the `path`. If it is, then you end that leg of the recursion to prevent cycling.

---

Updating to include a version where we capture material_cd cycles and only report those at the end of the recursion:

```
exec        pr_sys_drop_object '#BOMExploded'
;with BOM
as
(
    select 
        Prod_Plant_CD
    ,   Demand_Plant_CD
    ,   material_cd
    ,   component_cd
    ,   component_quantity
    ,   component_quantity   AS Calculated_Component_Quantity
    ,   BOM_Level
    ,   Demand_Quantity
    ,   CONVERT(float,1)     AS Produced_Ratio
    ,   Material_CD          AS Demand_Material_CD
    ,   CAST(material_cd AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Path
    ,   CAST(NULL AS CHAR(5)) as Cycle_Flag
    ,   0 as Cycle_Depth
    from #firstLevel a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        b.Plant_CD as 'Prod_Plant_CD' 
    ,   a.Demand_Plant_CD
    ,   b.Material_CD
    ,   b.Component_CD
    ,   b.component_quantity
    ,   b.component_quantity
    ,   a.BOM_Level + 1
    ,   a.Demand_Quantity
    ,   a.Produced_Ratio * a.Component_Quantity      -- Produced Quantity for the current level = Produced Quantity (level -1) * Component_Quantity (level -1)
    ,   a.Demand_Material_CD
    ,   a.Path + '|' + b.material_cd
    ,   CASE WHEN a.path NOT LIKE '%' + b.material_cd  + '%' then 'Cycle' END AS Cycle_Flag,
    ,   CASE WHEN a.path NOT LIKE '%' + b.material_cd  + '%' then a.Cycle_Depth + 1 END as Cycle_Depth
    FROM BOM a 
    inner join #BOM_ProdVersion_Priority b  
        on a.component_cd = b.material_cd
    inner join #base_routes c
        on a.Demand_Plant_CD = c.Recipient_Plant_CD 
       and b.Plant_CD        = c.Source_Plant_CD
       and c.Material_CD     = b.Material_CD   -- Need to have material_cd to link
    where b.Material_CD != b.Component_CD
    and   b.Component_Quantity > 0      
    and   a.cycle_depth < 2 --stop the query if we start cycling, but only after we capture at least one full cycle
)

select *
into #BOMExploded
from BOM
WHERE cycle_flag IS NOT NULL
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 20)
```

This will capture cycle_depth which is a counter that measures how deep into a cycle we get. We stop the recursion after we get to cycle_depth of 1 so the cycle can be captures in the final select.

Comment: Thank you, this is close to correct, as the purpose of the query is to simply find those paths that do in fact cycle. So the recursion must be halted once cycling begins. I was unaware of a setting that could stop the recursion and print out what has been found once cycling occurs, if anything....

Comment: With a few tweaks that should do the trick. You could add a case statement like `CASE WHEN a.path LIKE '%' + b.material_cd + '%' THEN 'CYCLE' END as CycleFlag` and then refer to that in your final SELECT statement's WHERE.

Comment: I added a second query that captures only cycles by going through all of the recursions, stopping any cycle after it makes a single cycle through, and then shows only the cycles in the final select.